# What are the differences between those words for bank transfers?

Tags: meaning

- wire transfer
- money transfer
- bank transfer
- remittance
- appropriation

I am confused because in German there is only the word *Banküberweisung* that, as far as I know, encompasses all of them.

I read that wire transfer goes back to when money was transfered via telegraph but is it still used today to refer to bank transfers? Of the mentioned words is there a dominating one, that I can use most of the time when talking about modern banks and online banking.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english) ...

> A wire transfer is a direct payment of money from one bank account into another
>
> Bank transfer ... a payment between two bank accounts

So, both wire transfer and bank transfer are defined as a transfer of money from one bank account to another. Although "wire transfer" may originally have referred to a particular form of bank transfer it remains [widely used](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bank-transfer) regardless of the actual means of transfer. They are both forms of money transfer executed by a bank or by an agent interacting with a bank on your behalf. So, if the context is money transferred between two bank accounts then I think you can use either "wire transfer" or "bank transfer".

The phrase "money transfer" is more general, if one party removes some cash from his/her wallet and hands it to another party then a money transfer has taken place but it is not a "bank transfer" or "wire transfer". That said, context might be enough to make clear that the type of "money transfer" in question is a formal or bank intermediated one
but if it is important to indicate the specific nature of a money transfer then using "bank transfer" or "wire transfer" might be more appropriate.

> A remittance is a sum of money that you send to someone.

Remittance describes the money which is being transferred

> An appropriation is an amount of money that a government or organization reserves for a particular purpose.

I don't think this belongs with the other terms, although an appropriation is (eventually) money it is not necessarily "bank" or "wire" transferred.